# Cocoa Touch serializing object. Trying to read data member of custom class after being decoded causes program to crash

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, serialization, protocols

I'm having what seems to be a rather strange error when attempting to encode and decode an object I created. I believe I made the object and all the objects it contains conform to NSCoding and NSCopying. I'm attempting to encode a NSMutableArray filled with "Goals" which have a NSString title and a NSMutableArray of "ActionSteps" which also conform to the protocols. I can encode the objects just fine and when I decode the objects they respond to function calls that don't deal with the data members, but when I try to read the title of on of the "Goals" the program crashes and I get this error message:

-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
 followed by a stack trace and finally:
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.

I get the same error message when I attempt to access the titles of the "ActionSteps" inside the goals.

Here is my code for the "goal" class for conforming to the protocols.

```
#pragma mark NSCoding
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
[encoder encodeObject:goalName forKey:GoalNameKey];
[encoder encodeObject:actionSteps forKey:ActionStepsKey];
}
```

This time I tried printing out whatever the decoder is returning as it should be an NSString and I got the same crash.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
if (self = [super init]) {
    goalName = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:GoalNameKey] retain];
    NSLog((NSString *)[decoder decodeObjectForKey:GoalNameKey]);
    actionSteps = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:ActionStepsKey] retain];
}
return self;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSCopying
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
Goal *copy = [[[self class] allocWithZone: zone] init];
copy.goalName = [[self.goalName copyWithZone:zone] autorelease];
copy.actionSteps = [[self.actionSteps copyWithZone:zone] autorelease];
return copy;
}
```

Here is the code for encoding the main NSMutableArray that contains all my "Goals":

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:goalViewController.goals toFile:[self dataFilePath]];
```

and for decoding:

```
NSString *filePath = [self dataFilePath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
    goalViewController.goals = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:filePath];
}
else {
    goalViewController.goals = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}
```

the error occurs when I try to read from the title of a "Goal" after It has been decoded

```
label.text = self.goal.goalName;
```

Comment: Do `NSLog(@"%@", [decoder objectForKey:GoalNameKey]);` instead of `NSLog((NSString *)[decoder decodeObjectForKey:GoalNameKey]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `ActionStepsKey` in both decode calls:

```
goalName = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:ActionStepsKey] retain];
actionSteps = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:ActionStepsKey] retain];
```

The first one should have `GoalNameKey`:

```
goalName = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:GoalNameKey] retain];
actionSteps = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:ActionStepsKey] retain];
```

Comment: I fixed this error and I the program still crashed in the same way

Comment: Does the `NSLog` you added in the decoding method correctly output the goal name now (without crashing)? And could you please give the context of the crashing line (`label.text = ...`)? Is `self` the view controller? Or another class? And what is `goal`? And how is `goal` set?

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. It was still crashing because there were improperly encoded objects in the iphone simulator sandbox. Deleting the app and rebuilding it fixed everything.